# How to generate a Symbols file for remote debugging using Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging, debug-symbols

My goal is to debug a VB.net project remotely. I could successfully see all the processes on the remote PC in the window appearing when choosing `Debug >> Attach to process..`.  My problem is in understanding the symbol file that is required to debug the project. I still do not know how to generate a symbols file? In what form should the file be? Why do I need symbol files to debug while I am the developer of the project?

Comment: If the code in Visual Studio is exactly the same as the code on the remote server it should work because you have the symbol files (.pdb) as part of the project output (bin folder).

Comment: What I have in the remote PC is the executable file, aka `.exe`. The file `.pdb` is there in the `release` folder but when I add its directory in the symbol location, VS does not recognize it as a symbol file and the debugger just does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Debug / Options / Debugging / Symbols and add the path where you have the PDB files (`c:\my\symbols` in the example below).

[image: Symbols in Visual Studio]